# How to swallow IOException as Custom Runtime Exception Java 8

Tags: java, exception, pdfbox

I'm using Apache PdfBox library and I'm noticing almost everything throws an IOException, and it's quite annoying to deal with considering most of the IOExceptions should actually be illegal state exceptions but it seems apache wanted clients to deal with it so they forced them as checked exceptions. Anyway...

My question is, how to wrap the IOException into a custom exception extending RuntimeException so the API is easier to deal with?

Example:

```
private final PDDocument document;
private final PDPage page;
private final PDFont font;

public PdfBoxWrapper(PDDocument document, PDPage page, PDFont font)
{
    this.document = document;
    this.page = page;
    this.font = Objects.isNull(font) ? PDType1Font.HELVETICA : font;

    this.document.addPage(this.page);

    try 
    {
        this.canvas = new PDPageContentStream(this.document, this.page);
    } 

    catch (IOException exception) {
        logger.error(exception.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Notice how I have to wrap PDPageContentStream in a try catch. How to Wrap the IOException from PdfBox as a PdfBoxIllegalStateException ?

as shown below:

```
public class PdfBoxIllegalStateException extends RuntimeException
{
    public PdfBoxIllegalStateException(String message)
    {
        super(message);
    }

    public PdfBoxIllegalStateException(String message, Throwable cause)
    {
        super(message, cause);
    }
}
```

Comment: So when you say 'swallow' you really mean 'rethrow'? Strange language.

Comment: No stranger than catching and throw exceptions :) Swallow just means to "catch" the exception, and throwing it back up if you will, means to "rethrow" the exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can catch the `IOException`, then wrap it in a `PdfBoxIllegalStateException` & then throw it again.

```
private final PDDocument document;
private final PDPage page;
private final PDFont font;

public PdfBoxWrapper(PDDocument document, PDPage page, PDFont font)
{
    this.document = document;
    this.page = page;
    this.font = Objects.isNull(font) ? PDType1Font.HELVETICA : font;

    this.document.addPage(this.page);

    try 
    {
        this.canvas = new PDPageContentStream(this.document, this.page);
    } 

    catch (IOException exception) {
        logger.error(exception.getMessage());
        throw new PdfBoxIllegalStateException(exception);
    }
}
```